# Can I use Ubuntu One Icons for 3rd party thingy?

Tags: ubuntu-one

So I am wondering what the guide lines are for using Ubuntu One icons as I have heard from a number of people that Ubuntu One has some propitiatory things to it. So I am not sure if I am to use there logo in something like this

http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~josephjamesmills/ubuntutv/fan_art/download/josephjamesmills%40gmail.com-20120728145710-sy00cvq1ja8o9qad/ubuntuoneactive.png-20120728145613-jtjdupswpqiocpb2-266/ubuntuone-active.png

If That is OK ?  I know that this might be a silly question but I do not want to get myself in trouble.Thanks so much for reading this and helping me with a project that helps others ;)

Answer (score 3):

We (U1) are working on some brand guidelines to provide icons and so on which can be used. Keep an eye on http://one.ubuntu.com/developer for details.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use the Ubuntu One (or Ubuntu) trademarks or logos without permission for 3rd party projects, no. They are only allowed to be used for the official things, unless written permission has been given to do so.